# Why is Pandoc stripping classes from my HTML fragments?

Tags: pandoc

I'm generating a bunch of HTML content containing code samples like this:

```
<pre>
  <code class="lang-css">
    img { opacity: ... }

  </code>
</pre>
```

... and wanting to concatenate it all into a single `book.html` using Pandoc. Broken down to the simplest version of the problem – I can concatenate a single file with this:

`pandoc test.html -o ../output/book.html`

Unfortunately, I'm getting this output:

```
 <pre>
  <code>
    img { opacity: ...
   }
  </code>
</pre>
```

That missing class is important to the syntax highlighter.

Any ideas on why this is happening and how I can stop it?

Cheers,

Comment: works for me in pandoc 2.0... but why would you even need pandoc to concatenate two html files?

Comment: Generally, I'm using other Pandoc flags to build a more complicated document than that. Like: 
     `pandoc -s --toc -c ../css/book.css sketch-1-draft.html etc .... -o ../output/book.html`

Comment: BTW, I've been using 'cat' to get around this. Works fine - just not as elegant as having Pandoc build the TOC and add the CSS. I'm on Pandoc 1.19 so will try the update to 2.0